# HANA column name sort

Tags: view, hana, calculation

In SAP HANA Calculation View, is there a way to order the column names certain way, without manually moving them up or down in order?

Answer (score 0):

Nope, there is no such thing. 
The order of the columns doesn't mean anything in SQL and if you as a developer have specific requirements to the order, it's likely not something like "alphabetic order", but some meaningful order (e.g. key columns, important, dimension or value columns first) and the editor cannot know what your rules are.